# NGINX Configuration showing "Welcome to nginx!"

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I am trying to install a new Nginx reverse proxy for a NodeJS application.
I've done it several times in the past and after hours of comparing the different configurations everything seems the same on both, but one works and the other one shows me the page:

> Welcome to nginx!
> If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required."

I am using an EC2 instance, I installed nginx with the following command:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install nginx
```

There are NO sites-available nor sites-enabled directories by default.
I configured the other server directly within conf.d (for testing purposes).
`sudo vim /etc/nginx/conf.d/testing.api.example.com`

I wrote the following configuration:

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        server_name testing.api.example.com;

        location / {
                    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8082;
                    proxy_set_header Host $host;
                    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

            }
}
```

I started nginx:

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

From the server I run a test to see if the server is running:

```
$ curl 127.0.0.1:8082
Hello Node!
```

The NodeJS server is running OK.

But when calling the port 80 for the reverse proxy, I've got the default "Welcome to nginx!" page.

It seems the nginx.conf file includes the conf.d folder:

```
# For more information on configuration, see:
#   * Official English Documentation: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
#   * Official Russian Documentation: http://nginx.org/ru/docs/

user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log notice;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/doc/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 4096;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    server {
        listen       80;
        listen       [::]:80;
        server_name  _;
        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;

        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;

        error_page 404 /404.html;
        location = /404.html {
        }

        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }

# Settings for a TLS enabled server.
#
#    server {
#        listen       443 ssl http2;
#        listen       [::]:443 ssl http2;
#        server_name  _;
#        root         /usr/share/nginx/html;
#
#        ssl_certificate "/etc/pki/nginx/server.crt";
#        ssl_certificate_key "/etc/pki/nginx/private/server.key";
#        ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:1m;
#        ssl_session_timeout  10m;
#        ssl_ciphers PROFILE=SYSTEM;
#        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
#
#        # Load configuration files for the default server block.
#        include /etc/nginx/default.d/*.conf;
#
#        error_page 404 /404.html;
#        location = /404.html {
#        }
#
#        error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
#        location = /50x.html {
#        }
#    }

}
```

I've tried several changes, but none are working...

Is there any other configuration missing?

Maybe the name_server is not correct?

I've tried:

```
server_name testing.api.example.com;
server_name 3.89.65.77;
#server_name 3.89.65.77; (commented)
server_name wach.quest;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It seems the nginx.conf file includes the conf.d folder:

If you look at the actual line in `nginx.conf` that includes the `conf.d` folder, you will see it only includes files in that folder that end in the `.conf` extension:

```
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
```

Your config file `/etc/nginx/conf.d/testing.api.example.com` does not have a `.conf` extension. You whould rename it to something like `/etc/nginx/conf.d/testing.api.example.com.conf`

Comment: Totally right @mark-b silly mistake missing the .conf filename

Answer (score -2):

If you are seeing the "Welcome to nginx!" page instead of your NodeJS application, it means that Nginx is not correctly configured to proxy the requests to your application.

To resolve this issue, you can follow these steps:

1. Make sure your NodeJS application is running and listening on a specific port (e.g., 3000).
2. Open your Nginx configuration file. The default location for the configuration file is usually `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf` or `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` depending on your system.
3. Inside the configuration file, locate the `server` block that corresponds to your domain or IP address. If it doesn't exist, you can create a new `server` block.
4. Within the `server` block, add the following configuration to define the reverse proxy:

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Replace with the actual address of your NodeJS application
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

5. Save the configuration file and exit.
6. Restart Nginx to apply the changes:

```bash
sudo service nginx restart
```

Make sure to replace `http://localhost:3000` in the `proxy_pass` directive with the actual address where your NodeJS application is running. This could be a local IP address, a domain name, or a different port depending on your setup.

After restarting Nginx, it should properly proxy the requests to your NodeJS application, and you should no longer see the "Welcome to nginx!" page.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;  # Replace with the actual address of your NodeJS application
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
}
```

Comment: This appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify issues.

Comment: This seems an autogenerated text, since even it makes sense. It doesn't solve my problem, mostly because it doesn't take into account my input (I've done all steps).

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds If you're not already, I strongly recommend flagging these answers for moderator intervention so that appropriate penalties can be meted out.

Comment: @DanielMann Thanks!  I normally would (and have over 1,200 helpful flags on AI answers), but with the Strike, we're holding off on flagging until things get resolved.  Some users are voluntarily cleaning up their AI-answers, and that's good.  For the others, I'm putting them in a "Saves" list to have reviewed when things get resolved on the Moderation side.